# Can "recall" be used in an imperative sense?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Can "**recall**" be used in an imperative sense, interchangeably with "**remember**", such as in "**Recall** that..." as if I was saying "**Remember** that..."

i.e. "John, recall I told you to go shopping"

Comment: It's really just short for the pedantic phrase "Let us recall", recapitulating some previous part of a lecture or book. It's the author/professor giving directions to the reader/student.

Comment: "Recall the Alamo!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a verb, it has an imperative form, but I don't think you'd use it as you did in your example. "Remember" as an imperative can mean (in advance) to remember something later. "Recall" isn't used in advance, and what people have already forgotten they can't reasonably be ordered to remember.

Where a "recall" imperative is used and makes sense is where you are telling someone to recall something you know they can remember, because you want them to reflect on it now. For instance, a history professor might say, "Recall what we learned about Hitler's narcotic abuse last week. With that in mind, what do you think his reaction to this move by the allies might have been?"

In your example, a more likely phrasing would be "John, if you recall, I told you to go shopping."

Comment: +Frances--I began more than a few cross examinations with "Recall event X" "Is it true that...?"  Further, I agree with Frances that recall is not the best imperative verb for your very informal sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  Lecturers, especially mathematicians, overuse "If you will recall, xxx."  (As if it would not be true, were you not to recall it?)  It degrades to "You recall xxx" or "Recall that xxx" as they go along.  It is quite common.

Comment: Thanks for specifying the mathematicians case, as that is where my doubt arose ;)

Answer (score 1):

A different sense of 'recall" is often used in the imperative , the sense meaning "to call back". For example:

> Sergent, recall the patrol.

That is clearly an imperative sentence, but has nothing to do with memory